# How do I force Safari to show me Google search result pages in history?

Tags: macos, safari, high-sierra, browser-history

Safari's history doesn't seem to include Google search result pages.

Steps I go through which re-create this issue every time:

1. Search for anything from Safari's omnibar.
2. Visit a result (by clicking it).
3. Optional step: do anything else in Safari.
4. Hit <kbd>⌘</kbd>+<kbd>Y</kbd> to load up the history.
5. Enjoy *not* seeing that intermediary Google results page in the list.

This is really frustrating.

How can I force Safari to show me Google search result pages in history?

I'm using Safari 11.0 (13604.1.38.1.6) and macOS High Sierra 10.13.

Comment: I guess you can add Google as a favorite bookmark, and turn on the ⌘1 shortcut to go to the first favorite bookmark from Safari preferences

Comment: @SkeletonBow how does that help me out?

Comment: You can go to google using that shortcut, and it'll be saved to the history. Of course it's a mere workaround

Comment: @SkeletonBow I think you might have misunderstood my problem. Even if I  google _for_ something using your method, the results page isn't pushed to history.

Comment: Ah, okay. Sorry.

Comment: Did you ever find an answer to this? I'm dealing with the same thing

Comment: Also, I've found that if you _don't_ click a result then the results page _will_ be saved ¯\\_(ツ)_/¯

Comment: @Wmbuch I haven't found an answer yet unfortunately

Comment: This also occurs if you go to www.google.com directly and then search, rather than using the omnibar to search

Comment: This appears to only be the case (in my version of Safari at least) when using Google.  The other supported search engines in Safari do not remove the search page from the search history.

Answer (score 2):

Click `History > Search Results SnapBack` or `⌥⌘S` via keyboard shortcut

[image]

Comment: This has some unfortunate limitations over it simply appearing in the history: it only works in the same tab the search was performed, and it only works for the most recent search performed in that tab.

Comment: You mean use this instead of the back button?

Comment: @theonlygusti At the time this post was created Safari had an annoying behaviour that navigating via the back button skipped Google search results pages. It appears to have been fixed since then, thankfully!